# How do I mutate multiple columns returned by a function into another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe `songs`:

```
|artistName   |trackName                 |id                     |duration |
|:------------|:-------------------------|:----------------------|:--------|
|Shaan        |Woh Ladki Hai Kahan       |2tO0QPdCA0jgDBshTuYYkc |306133   |
|Amit Trivedi |Zinda                     |1gEHNfJRSXpDVaEicwRRfe |241962   |
|flora cash   |You're Somebody Else      |0pdKRp2sUthTPe7RLWpPqQ |218883   |
|Iron & Wine  |Each Coming Night         |2xa9PoO42d7VjT0KqG5d3I |207773   |
|Yasser Desai |Tenu Na Bol Pawaan        |5mp7og60TpyNiKi2p9Morw |295352   |
|ERock        |Jurassic Park Meets Metal |4u0RJ8g7QM5exHIPvJ0WW3 |244000   |
```

I am interested in the `id` column. This is used by the `get_track_audio_features()` function from the `{spotifyr}` package to return a dataframe of a track's audio features. For example, one id might return:

```
| danceability| energy| key| loudness| mode| speechiness| acousticness| instrumentalness| liveness| valence|  tempo|type           |id                     |uri                                  |track_href                                               |analysis_url                                                     | duration_ms| time_signature|
|------------:|------:|---:|--------:|----:|-----------:|------------:|----------------:|--------:|-------:|------:|:--------------|:----------------------|:------------------------------------|:--------------------------------------------------------|:----------------------------------------------------------------|-----------:|--------------:|
|         0.47|  0.237|   2|  -15.593|    1|      0.0348|        0.837|            0.464|    0.115|   0.358| 81.268|audio_features |2xa9PoO42d7VjT0KqG5d3I |spotify:track:2xa9PoO42d7VjT0KqG5d3I |https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2xa9PoO42d7VjT0KqG5d3I |https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/2xa9PoO42d7VjT0KqG5d3I |      207773|              4|
```

What I would like to do is add certain audio features, for example `energy` and `danceability` into `songs`, corresponding to their IDs. The resulting dataframe becomes:

```
| id                     | artistName   | trackName            | duration | energy | danceability |
|------------------------|--------------|----------------------|----------|--------|--------------|
| 0pdKRp2sUthTPe7RLWpPqQ | flora cash   | You're Somebody Else | 2349023  | .47    | .13          |
| 1gEHNfJRSXpDVaEicwRRfe | Amit Trivedi | Zinda                | 234009   | .15    | .78          |
```

I thought of making use of the `rowwise()` function to do this and mutating everything into a single column and then separating it (since they'll be separated by commas and can be made into new columns):

```
song_data <- songs %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(song_data_id = toString(get_track_audio_features(id)) %>%
    separate(.,
             song_data_id,
             into =  c("danceablity", "energy"),
             sep = ",")
```

I thought this would work, since the first two columns of what the function returns are danceability and energy and that the rest would be discarded. However, it doesn't and instead gives me the following error:

```
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

How can I accomplish mutating multiple columns into my dataframe, in the shortest possible way?

Dput:

```
structure(list(endTime = structure(c(1588582680, 1588640040, 
1588640040, 1588640280, 1588640280, 1588641240), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), artistName = c("Shaan", "Amit Trivedi", 
"flora cash", "Amit Trivedi", "flora cash", "flora cash"), trackName = c("Woh Ladki Hai Kahan", 
"Zinda", "You're Somebody Else", "Zinda", "You're Somebody Else", 
"You're Somebody Else"), msPlayed = c(17253L, 0L, 218649L, 1504L, 
218883L, 638496L), date = structure(c(18386, 18387, 18387, 18387, 
18387, 18387), class = "Date"), time = structure(c(52080, 23040, 
23040, 23280, 23280, 24240), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function returns a dataframe, we can store that into a column as a list using the `map` function from `{purrr}`. `map()` always returns a list.

```
features <- song_data %>% 
  nest(data = c(id)) %>%
  mutate(audio_features = map(data, ~ get_track_audio_features(.$id))) %>% 
  unnest(., audio_features)
```

The audio features are then stored in a column called `audio_features` but this is still a list. The last line, the `unnest()` function expands the list into separate columns. All done!

Answer (score -1):

If you add the `id` to the results of `get_track_audio_features()` you can combine the tables with join, e.g. `left_join` or `inner_join`.